# How to sum up unique returned values

Tags: sql

I am trying to Sum up the unique row values.

Basically I have 3 sets of returned values. I need a new column that will give me the total for each grouping.

The script is in the photo attached

As you can see in the image, the "Fee Amounts Per Fee" column shows that invoice 17895 has 2 line items. $95 and $50. I am trying to get a new column to show up that will give me a total of $145. It's ok if there are two rows with that value, since there are two returns for invoice.

[pic from the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38dzw.jpg)
[pic from excel showing what i am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51NGF.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your data as text in your questions, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, your image is cutting off important information in Column A. The first four rows look like the same invoice number.

Comment: As a hint, it sounds like you want to use window functions.  Google that, you'll get tons of information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I used a CTE table and then used in this way:

```
with temp_cte 
        as
                (
            select 
                    inv.INVOICENUMBER as [Invoice Number]
                ,sum (comp.BASEAMOUNT) as [Total Of Fees]

            from CMCODECASEFEE ccf
                join CACOMPUTEDFEE COMP on ccf.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = comp.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
                join CAINVOICEFEE inf on comp.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = inf.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
                join CAINVOICE inv on inf.CAINVOICEID = inv.CAINVOICEID
                join CASTATUS st on inv.CASTATUSID = st.CASTATUSID

            where
                comp.FEENAME like 'MAG -%'
            and 
                st.CASTATUSID in (1,3,6,7)
                group by inv.INVOICENUMBER
                )

        select 
             inv.INVOICENUMBER as [Invoice Number]
            ,convert (date,inv.INVOICEDATE) as [Invoice Date]
            ,st.name as [Invoice Status]
            ,comp.FEENAME as [Fee Name]
            ,comp.BASEAMOUNT as [Fee Amount Per Fee]
            ,comp.AMOUNTPAIDTODATE as [Amount Paid]
            ,temp_cte.[Total Of Fees]
        from CMCODECASEFEE ccf
            join CACOMPUTEDFEE COMP on ccf.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = comp.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
            join CAINVOICEFEE inf on comp.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = inf.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
            join CAINVOICE inv on inf.CAINVOICEID = inv.CAINVOICEID
            join CASTATUS st on inv.CASTATUSID = st.CASTATUSID
            join temp_cte on inv.INVOICENUMBER = temp_cte.[Invoice Number]

        where
            comp.FEENAME like 'MAG -%'
        and 
            st.CASTATUSID in (1,3,6,7)
        and inv.INVOICEDATE between @StartDate and @EndDate
```